# How to store user input as a variable in an async function in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, prompt

Basically I am looking for a substitute to var x = prompt("Question") inside of an asynchronous function specifically for node.js. Does such a thing exist? I have tried dependencies such as inquirer but I am getting unhandled promise rejection warnings.

Comment: Could you please post  a piece of code, so we can get  an idea on what you mean? By the way could you please explain why prompt() is bad in your case? Also unhandled promise rejection warnings appears because you are not handling promise rejections in case an error occurs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))